# Display all running processes of android devices through python

Tags: android

i want to show all the running processes of android through Linux commands and modules..i.e task manager. is it possible to run Linux terminal commands on android devices with the help of python, so that it shows all the running processes of android? or is there any other way?please give some possible solutions to this question and provide some helpful links...

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course there is! You can download any terminal emulator (search the Playstore), and when you open your terminal, enter the "ps" command.

Comment: actually i am working on operating system project. i want to make an android task manager. that will show all the currently running processes of android.. can it be possible to develop this through linux..?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Linux to develop the app? It really doesn't matter. Java doesn't support that because of the virtual machine. If you want to get a list of running processes, you can do that with the "ps" command. You'd have to read the stdout of the binary and parse the results, but that's the only way you can do it. If you are asking how to list running Android applications, the Android SDK provides that functionality. Google around if that's the case. But if you are truly trying to list all running processes in Java, the only way to do it is through external binaries.